# Extracting raster pixel value in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am dealing with some very large geotiff files (the whole of Canada at a 250m resolution) and is having trouble to extract the pixels value as I need to do some calculations for mapping ecosystem services (carbon,timber volume, biodiversity etc.). To do so, I need all the pixel value and we have around 4.37 billion raster pixels across Canada. I have tried Python code or convert from raster point but could not success. Then I tried to clip the raster by provenance but it only convert ~ 1/6 part of BC afterward it stopped working.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to extract pixel values with certain polygon zones? Have you tried Zonal Statistics as Table?: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000

Comment: Maybe try Raster to ASCII file?

Comment: Do you have the spatial analyst extension?

Comment: Aaron: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried but it did not work, gave a error and saying only single band integer raster dataset is a valid input. Our pixel type is floating point. It would be highly appreciated if you could give some other idea.

Comment: Pete: Thanks for your comments but it did not work either. When I convert from raster to ACSII got 0.9999 value for all cells.

Comment: Are your images multi-bands or single band?

Comment: What sort of calculations? You may not need to extract values if you can run those calculations directly against the raster using map algebra. Otherwise you might be better off sampling the raster.

Comment: Are you limited to the ArcGIS GUI, or are you willing to go into Python or R?

Comment: Luku: Thanks for your suggestion. Although this method is working but has some limitations and would be work intensive procedure to reach the ultimate goal of our project.

Comment: Mikkel Lydholm Rasmussen: Thanks, Could you please let me know bit detail about your suggestion. I can use R.

Comment: What do you mean by "...I need all the pixel value..."? What does your intended output look like?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would copy the raster data to a file geodatabase, assuming it is a geotiff or something comparable. ArcGIS a lot faster using a geodatabase.

In a second step I would use map algebra to multiply the raster with 1000.

In a third step you can now save the raster as 16 bit integer (or other integer format needed for you data precision).

By using step 2 and 3 you can get rid of float and keep the precision. Additionally you will be able to use the extract values by point tool.

Comment: Generic Militzer: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I can go up to 2nd steps. In third steps, when I wanted to  save the raster as 16 bit integer but I could not find it (16 bit integer). I am using ArcGIS 10.1. Could you please give me bit details suggestion about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of each single pixel then you could try to create a fishnet with the cell size equal to the pixel extent and then use "Zonal Statistics as Table" to give you only the sum.

This may take a while though.

Comment: M.Wong: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried but it did not work.